# Onclick after effects animation (bodymovin.js) ID nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a after effects bodymovin.js SVG animation with ID's on certain paths (image attached). I've put some css styles on these (`cursor:pointer`), which work fine but using jquery onClick for a redirect doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas why?

The animation itself is in an overlay which starts after a button is pressed.

The redirect code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
        document.getElementById("replay").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
    };
    });
</script>
```

The animation code:

```
<script>
$( ".animation" ).click(function() {
    var anim;
    var elem = document.getElementById('bodymovin_overlay')
    var animData = {
        container: elem,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: true,
        rendererSettings: {
            progressiveLoad:false
        },
        path: 'data_overlay.json'
    };
    anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);
});
</script>
```

Also the image is attached:
[image]

Comment: it should be document.getElementById("replay"), excluded # to bind the id property i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code that worked, hope it helps someone:

```
    var lookingForLinks = true;
    setTimeout(addLinksToSvgAnim, 1000);

    function addLinksToSvgAnim() {
        if (lookingForLinks) {
            let medicalG = document.getElementById("medical");
            let foodG = document.getElementById("food");
            let collabG = document.getElementById("collab");
            let volunteersG = document.getElementById("volunteers");
            let projectsG = document.getElementById("projects");
            let replayG = document.getElementById("replay");

            if (medicalG && foodG && volunteersG && projectsG) {
                lookingForLinks = false;
                medicalG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/medical-aid";
                });
                foodG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/humanitarian-aid";
                });
                collabG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/our-story/partners";
                });
                volunteersG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/get-involved";
                });
                projectsG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/bringhope-projects";
                });
                replayG.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + "/bringhope-projects";
                });
            }
            setTimeout(addLinksToSvgAnim, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove # from document.getElementById("#replay").

Use document.getElementById("replay") (Native JS) or via jQuery $('#replay')

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error occurs because you forgot to add a semi-colon.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('bodymovin_overlay')
```

to

```
var elem = document.getElementById('bodymovin_overlay');
```

Comment: try using jQuery for $("#replay").on('click', function() { //do something });

Comment: Issue solved. The overlay z-index was covering the animation so the click was not happening

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved - the overlay was covering the animations z-index, had to give it a higher z-index than the overlay.